# jquery timepicker minimum time settings

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set minimum time for End time based on the selected value of Start time by using Jquery Timepicker plugin.

```
 $('#start_time').timepicker({timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',ampm: true,hour:10,
                                    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                                       $('#end_time').timepicker("option","hourMin", '10');
                                    }
                                 });
```

The above code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using the timepicker addon by [Trent Richardson](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

This is a know [issue](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/195) for this timepicker and a fix has been requested. So it might be fixed/added in future releases of the addon.

For now you can use a (dirty) fix like in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dHYhk/4/).